# NvChad not showing colors correctly (mac os)

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin, telescope.nvim

I've installed NvChad for NeoVim. Followed all instuctions as stated in docs and as I've seen on some youtube videos, but in my installation the colors look weird. Here is a short video of me trying to choose a theme:

[image: GIF showing theme selection]

As you can see, I'm not able to see all text with any of them. Something is always unreadable (title, breadcrumb, main text, etc.) Any ideas? Preferably without switching to iTerm2. I'm on Ventura 13.4.1 (22F82).

I expeced it to look like this:

[YouTube - Turn VIM into a full featured IDE with only one command](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mtgo-nP_r8Y)

or as shown in [official docs](https://nvchad.com/docs/features)

Comment: `export TERM=xterm-256color` did not do the trick.
iTerm2 works fine though.

Comment: Doesn't show colors correctly for me in GNU screen either, but I think I've seen somewhere once that someone else was having a similar issue... maybe somehow related?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out [here](https://github.com/NvChad/NvChad/discussions/1939) by one of the main contributors, the Mac OS default terminal does not support true colors.
When clicking the link, you can also find some alternatives (alacritty/wezterm/kitty) to using iTerm2 as well.

Comment: Thanks! Switched to iTerm2 at the end.

Comment: I am facing the same issues in the iTerm2 When I am inside a GNU screen window.  have you got any solutions for that? I have tried `term screen-256color` but it did not solve the issue